# SQL Server 2008 connection is slow when not working with appliction few minutes

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-2008, connection

My application is in C# 2008 and I did not have any problem when using SQL Server 2005.

When I upgraded to SQL Server 2008, I found than first function using SQL takes more than 10 seconds. And every time that application is not being used for several minutes it repeats.

I'm using `DataTableAdapter` to connect to SQL Server.

The connection string is

```
Data Source=Server-PC;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123;Connect Timeout=60
```

I replaced Server name by IP but no change happened.

Both server and clients have the same problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do in SQL Server? Without more information it's nearly impossible to say. Also, 10 seconds isn't terribly long in database time. It would be wise to anticipate delays when retrieving data from a RDBMS. Many things from server maintenance to server load can cause queries to run slower than they do in development.

Comment: You can also use SQL Profiler to determine if there's a problem with your query. If you see a long duration with your query, the issue lies there. If it is processed quickly, the issue is somewhere else (network, etc).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx